Jordan decomposition of $GL_n$ over perfect fields
Matrices in $g\in GL_n$ over a perfect field $k$ have a (unique) Jordan decomposition, i.e. there exist unique $g_u$ and $g_s$ such that $g=g_u\cdot g_s = g_s\cdot g_u$ where $g_u$ is unipotent ($(g_u-1)^N=0$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$) and where $g_s$ is semi-simple (meaning diagonalizable over the algebraic closure of $k$).
I'm not sure how to prove this for perfect fields. For algebraically closed fields you can use the Jordan normal form of a matrix to immediately get a diagonal matrix and an upper triangular matrix with $1$'s on the diagonal, but I don't know how to generalize this to perfect fields. I think one needs to find a find $g_s$ over the algebraic closure of $k$ and then find a basis transformation such that $g_s$ (and the basis) have entries in $k$, but I'm not sure on how to do that.
Any help is appreciated!

Are you familiar with rational canonical form? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form

Wikipedia points to Chapter 9 in W. Waterhouse "Introduction to affine group schemes" (1979), this is the first theorem on p. 68. It follows from uniqueness of $g_s$ and $g_u$: if $g \in GL_n(k)$, then for every $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$, $g = \sigma(g) = \sigma(g_s g_u) = \sigma(g_s) \sigma(g_u)$, $\sigma(g_s)$ is separable and thus equals $g_s$. So $g_s$ is fixed by all automorphisms and lies in $k$.

@Amateur_Algebraist Thank you, you probably mean semi-simple instead of seperable right

@QiaochuYuan Sadly not
